# Function misbehaves when acting on a regular expression group (Clojure)

Tags: regex, clojure

The following code has an error that surprises me. My goal is to replace something that's wrapped in double square brackets with the markdown formatting for a relative link. The "slug" function is a helper to remove spaces and change file extensions. It seems to work fine when I call it directly--it turns "its a link" into "its-a-link.html". But when I call it on `"$1"`it fixes file extensions but does not turn spaces into hyphens. This is the first time I've used `"$1"` so that's my bet as to where the problem is.

```
(ns grothendieck.nanoformats
  (:require [clojure.string :as string])
  (:require [swiss.arrows :refer :all]))

(defn slug [f]
  "Replaces a filename's spaces with friendly hyphens and prepares its file extension."
  (-<> f
      (string/lower-case)
      (string/replace <> " " "-")
      (string/replace <> #"\.(wiki|md)" "")
      (str <> ".html")))

(defn internal-links [text]
  (string/replace text #"\[\[(.+)\]\]" (str "[$1](" (slug "$1") ")")))
```

Comment: Does this engine use BRE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `slug` gets `"$1"` as an argument, because the `str` form is fully evaluated before `string/replace` sees it. You want not a pattern string, but a function.

```
(defn internal-links
  [text]
  (string/replace text #"\[\[(.+)\]\]"
                  (fn [[full-match first-group]]
                    (str "[" first-group "](" (slug first-group) ")"))))
```

Comment: Oh! Of course--I think using the swiss arrows got me thinking I can just thread any old thing and it will do what I mean rather than what I say.